# How to do auto increment for input field in Angular 8?

Tags: html, angular

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MkMY.png) If click on Add symbol each row will be added so index should increment automatically
Please someone explain me?

```
<div class="form-row">
        <div
          class="form-row"
          *ngFor="let temp of logger.temperature; let i = index"
        >
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <input
              name="tempindex+{{ i }}"
              [(ngModel)]="temp.index"
              type="number"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Index"
              required
            />
          </div>
```

If click on Add symbol each row will be added so index should increment automatically
Please someone explain me?

Comment: Yes .i'm using mongodb

Comment: See i've uploaded the image also,please check it .

Comment: Does https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-rows-dynamically-formgroup-formarray?file=src/app/app.component.ts help you? You just need to add an input box and do the property binding in value

Comment: Hi Varman ,yes i understood but i need Index values in the box.If  i try to add index field should increment automatically.So how to do that?

Comment: Varman in your stackblitz code title is there know..in my case in that place index field  is there .if i add new one, index field should be automatically increment.please help me

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have added the answer

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dynamically add rows, its better you to use reactive form. YOu just need to add

```
<tbody formArrayName="gaugeTitles"
    *ngFor="let item of gaugeTitleForm.get('gaugeTitles').controls; let i = index;">
    <tr [formGroupName]="i">
       <td><input type="text" [value]="i+1"></td>
       <td><input type="text" formControlName="name"></td>
       <!-- Other fields -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-rows-dynamically-formgroup-formarray-so-answer?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: In UI it is coming ..but in DB(mangodb)it is showing null.so if you know please tell me.Thank you varman.

Comment: You cant add the mongodb question here . So open another question, post your porblrm

Comment: If the answer helps you to your currnt angular question, please click on tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question –

Comment: But what if you want to include this data in formgroup?